# Python: sqlite3 - how to speed up updating of the database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-update

I have a database, which I store as a `.db` file on my disk. I implemented all the function neccessary for managing this database using `sqlite3`. However, I noticed that updating the rows in the table takes a large amount of time. My database has currently 608042 rows. The database has one table - let's call it `Table1`. This table consists of the following columns:

```
id | name | age | address | job | phone | income
```

(`id` value is generated automaticaly while a row is inserted to the database).
After reading-in all the rows I perform some operations (ML algorithms for predicting the income) on the values from the rows, and next I have to update (for each row) the value of `income` (thus, for each one from 608042 rows I perform the `SQL update` operation).
In order to update, I'm using the following function (copied from my class):

```
def update_row(self, new_value, idkey):
    update_query = "UPDATE Table1 SET income = ? WHERE name = ?" % 
    self.cursor.execute(update_query, (new_value, idkey))
    self.db.commit()
```

And I call this function for each person registered in the database.

```
for each i out of 608042 rows:
  update_row(new_income_i, i.name)
```

(values of new_income_i are different for each i).
This takes a huge amount of time, even though the dataset is not giant. Is there any way to speed up the updating of the database? Should I use something else than `sqlite3`? Or should I instead of storing the database as a .db file store it in memory (using `sqlite3.connect(":memory:")`)?

Comment: Have you tried to create index on column `name`, or even use `id` to update those records? If `name` is unique to each row, you can even try to create an unique index on column `name`, but I believe using `id` should be fast, since it is numeric other than string.

Comment: @JoeyZhang Id is unique, names are not necessarily. Could you please tell a little bit more what this index is suppose to do and how it can help?

Comment: see "How does database indexing work?"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work

Comment: Consider using a database that supports stored procedures so that you can implement your ML algorithm as a stored procedure that can be applied in a single UPDATE statement, rather than having to move all the data to Python and then the results back one row at a time.

Comment: @rd_nielsen Can you maybe suggest any databases that support stored procedures or any tutorial/blog post where I can read about this?

Comment: @rd_nielsen SQLite is an embedded database; it does not have client/server communication overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Each UPDATE statement must scan the entire table to find any row(s) that match the name.

An index on the `name` column would prevent this and make the search much faster. (See [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) and [How does database indexing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work))

However, if the `name` column is not unique, then that value is not even suitable to find individual rows: each update with a duplicate name would modify all rows with the same name. So you should use the `id` column to identify the row to be updated; and as the primary key, this column already has an implicit index.

Comment: Thanks for the explanaition!